# How can I simplify a LIDAR scan?

Tags: mesh

I've got a LIDAR scan of a series of rooms, and I'd love to be able to modify it so I end up with simple boxes for rooms I can create shadowcatching surfaces from.

From a conceptual level, I need to be able to identify the largest more-or-less flat portions of each surface as the  wall/floor/ceiling and create flat planes from them, and deleting all those things that aren't wall/floor/ceiling.

From a practical level, though, I've got no idea how to start the process! Are there plugins or programs that can help me achieve this? Is this a task for some sort of AI approach that could be trained to "see" the bounding box of wall/floor/ceiling, ignoring the noise of smaller details within the box?

Or can it be a simpler process that deconstructs the mesh according to specific constraints?

Sorry I'm so vague about this - I am trying to understand how this process could be started, what sort of approaches could be taken.[image: Lidar room scan]

Comment: You could start with the decimate modifier.

Comment: Yes, that's a great start! Thanks!

Comment: Question - is it possible to assign the same value to, say, the Z coordinates for a number of selected vertices?

Comment: Select them and scald them to zero on the Z acis by pressing S (scale) >Z>0.

Comment: I've used Chat GPT to write a script that allows me to replace any particular coordinate among the selected vertices, whether X, Y, or Z with the desired value. Works great1

Can't code for shit, but this is an instance where it looks like Chat GPT can actually help. Amazing!